# About the benefits of const for Stateles widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a custom appbar:

```
class _MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverAppBar(
      title: Text('Catalog', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1),
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

and usage of it

```
return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          _MyAppBar(),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox(height: 12)),
          ...
```

In that code `const` using wildly (it's the Flutter team code as an example of a particular package usage) and why in this case `const` isn't used for `_MyAppBar()` (we could add const constructor in _MyAppBar  definition)?

Answer (score 4):

When you create a widget and is able to prefix it with `const` that widget will not rebuild. The framework knows not to rebuild such widgets because it can tell that the objects did not change. Constant objects are resolved at compile-time, and due to a process known as canonicalization if two or more objects have the same parameters, and are constant, they will refer to the same instance.

For example, if you have

```
@override
Widget build() {
  const MyWidget();
}
```

And then somewhere you call setState, MyWidget will not be reconstructed because it was already resolved at compile-time, and the framework will also not call its build method which makes sense because non of the arguments passed to MyWidget (which are none here) has changed as a result of issuing the rebuild so the configuration is still the same.

Moreover if somewhere else you call `const MyWidget();` you will still refer to the same object/instance so it's more optimal.

And they added the lint rule so that people add a `const` constructor and are able to invoke their widgets/classes with `const` and it uses by default in flutter. Flutter apps, packages, and plugins created with `flutter create` starting with Flutter version 2.3.0 are already set up to use the lints defined in this package.

**Disabling individual rules**

```
include: package:lints/recommended.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    avoid_shadowing_type_parameters: false
    await_only_futures: true
```

For more read this [analysis option](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options) and [const keyword](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-flutter-const-keyword-demystified-c8d2a2609a80).

After reading this, it would be helped you to understand why in your case `const` isn't used for `_MyAppBar()`.

SRC From: [remove const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69341612/can-i-remove-const-in-the-below-flutter-code/69341928#69341928)

Comment: Anilitcs options are only helps to use the right and prefered code style and even they would include `prefer_const_constructors` in the options we still need explicit constructor definition in class. So I suppose they could use `const` with `_MyAppBar()` (and explicit constructor ib class definition) so it would be more usefull for readers.

Comment: You sound a lot like me lol

Answer (score 0):

when you use const behind widgets it changes the way it is rebuilt it will not rebuild completely from scratch when you setState the widget.it uses the data that has been stored on ram and rebuilds it with that.
when your widget does not change with rebuilding the page it is recommended to improve the application behavoiur